# ps command and etime

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I'm trying to get all ruby process running on my server that are alive for more than 24 hours.

With PS i can get this:

```
ps -eo pid,etime,cmd | grep .rb | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1, $2}'
```

The output:

```
PID   ELAPSED
23484 07:54:41
23493 07:54:41
23504 07:54:41
23515 07:54:41
23535 07:54:40
23548 07:54:40
23670 07:54:37
31671 3-07:54:49
31807 3-07:54:48
31832 3-07:54:48
32308 3-07:54:40
32318 3-07:54:40
32331 3-07:54:40
```

In this case, 6 process are running for more than 24h.

So, how can I filter this column to get only what I need?

My idea was to use awk, something like

```
awk '$2 > XXXX'
```

But I don't know what is the unit of the elapsed column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of coupling multiple commands in a pipe-line, you can just use a single `ps` command with its `--sort` feature to sort based on running time and filter results needed by `Awk`

```
ps -eo pid,etime,cmd --sort=start_time | awk '/\.rb/ && /[1-9]+[-]/'
```

The meaning of the filter `/\.rb/ && /[1-9]+[-]/` means, filter lines containing pattern `.rb` (`.` is a meta-character which needs to be escaped) and lines containing a number (one or more days `[1-9]+`) followed by a `-`, so if there are entries of form `3-07:54:40`, the part `3-` is matched to indicate more than 24h.

According to the [POSIX documentation for `ps`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html)

> **etime**
>
> In the `POSIX` locale, the elapsed time since the process was started, in the form:
> `[[dd-]hh:]mm:ss`
> where `dd` shall represent the number of days, `hh` the number of hours, mm the number of minutes, and `ss` the number of seconds. The `dd` field shall be a decimal integer. The `hh`, `mm`, and `ss` fields shall be two-digit decimal integers padded on the left with zeros.

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -eo pid,etime,comm,user | awk '$2~/[0-9][0-9]*-/ && /\.rb/ {print }'
```

Comment: Hey there and welcome to SO! It would be beneficial to your answer if you were to add some more explanation as to how this bit of code solves the problem :)